# How to have menu items in columns instead of everything vertical

Tags: interface

When I watch the youtube channel "Blender Secrets" then I notice his menu items takes a lot less space then they do with mine.

This is is how he has it:

[image]

This is how my blender looks like:

[image]

I would really like how he has it cause blender can be really scroll heavy.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect you're using version Blender 2.90.1 which for some reason does use the single list layout  whereas he is using version 2.83. You can still get version 2.83 as it's a long term support (LTS) version.

Comment: Thanks, I will check tommorow when I have descent internet.

Comment: https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-83/ is the download page.

Comment: You can get 2.83 as John said, but instead of scrolling I recommend holding middle mouse button and scroll it down. I believe your scroll will be wider

Comment: I checked and it indeed works in 2.83. Does someone know why it does not work past 2.83?

Comment: I posted a bug report in case it is a bug
https://developer.blender.org/T82897

Comment: It's intended: https://developer.blender.org/D7430